# Trying to show stability of a second order differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Hi guys I am trying to prove that the solution for $x''+x=0$ has a solution that is stable, but not asymptotically stable. The hardest part of the proof is that we never actually defined stable for anything other than first order equation.

Definition:
The solution $x=0$ is stable if for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta$ such that if $x(t)$ is a solution of $x'=Ax$ where A is a constant matrix and $x(0)=x_0$ and $||x||<\delta$ implies that $||x(t)||< \epsilon$ for all $t$.

My thinking is that for second order differential equation we need to let that $x(0)=\delta$ and $x'(0)= \delta_1$ then just look at the abs of the solution 
$|x(t)|=| \delta cos(t)+\delta_1 sin(t)| \leq \delta + \delta_1$. 
Am I correct? Also I think this is not asymptotically because as we take $t \rightarrow  \infty$ it does not go to zero. 
 Also can someone please actually help me see the definition for higher order differential equations, so far I was unable to see it.

Comment: You can rewrite a second order differential equation as a system of two first order equations.

Comment: I thought that is only true only for linear DF

Comment: $x'(t) = A x(t) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) x(t)$

Comment: @Kori This ODE is definitely linear...

Comment: @Kori the same technique can be applied to reduce a non-linear second order ODE to a non-linear system of first order ODE's.